# Generate password for one login apex oracle

Tags: oracle-apex

I have screen without authentication,  any one can login to this page and fill the feiled ,after that the manager check the data  and approve or return to user for update his data , when change status to return, the system send link by email to user to update the data .
How I can generate automatic password for one login only . when open the link  and send the password to user To login . (Like OTP).
Note  the link should contain the Id  related to inserted data to get all data (form region )
login deferent sessions because I use the collection. 
Example:-
f?p=App:Page:Session:Request:Debug:ClearCache:itemNames:itemValues:123

Comment: I'm confused by several points, let's start with the first: You said, "I have screen without authentication, any one can login to this page and fill the feiled..." If the page has no authentication, why would they "login"? Did you mean "access"?

Comment: i am Sorry for this mistake , yes I mean access , after submit data, the admin confirm data or return data to user for  modify. The user can modify the data by link  were send to him by email . this link to   login in  page  to modify his data,this page it's form region , in a link I want send the Id to fill data in form , befor login I want to send password for only  one login. when trying open the link

Comment: No worries... Next question: if the user doesn't authenticate to submit the data at first, how will you know who to send the email to for edits?

Comment: One of the item in page it's the email ,for clarification,  I am working on CRM system the vendor  or partner  fill his data in this page . After that the admin approve or not approve,  some time the data not clear ,for this I want send this link to user

Comment: I see. And how long will the password be good for? Will it expire after the first edit? What if the person was making edits and accidentally hit submit, how could they finish making the edits? You'll need to think about what happens when someone tries to use an expired password.

Comment: I think before submit, the confirm message will appear , when try login by expired password the system send a message to admin .

Comment: You could use rejoin session functionality? https://community.oracle.com/thread/4099442 Or add GUID to link and enable one timed usage?

Comment: I'm starting to lean toward a GUID/random key embedded in a link. @jaw, the basic idea would be to store a random value in a table that's associated with the user that submitted the form. Then, when you send the email, you'd add a link with the random value embedded so that it passes to session state. For example: `https://example.com/ords/f?p=101:1:::::P1_FORM_GUID:9CBD4F17AE7646E8E0530C4072646424`. Then, on that page, you'd add a "Before Header" process that would validate the value of P1_FORM_GUID. Would that work?